# Создание сессий пользователей Flask

Tags: python, сессия, flask

Использую python Flask для веб приложения.
Не могу разобраться с сессиями. Насмотрелся кучу примеров, но в голове ясной картины использования нет.
Вот к примеру какой код пишут для создания сессий.

```
def login():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      session['username'] = request.form['username']
      return redirect(url_for('index'))
   return '''


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
       # remove the username from the session if it is there
       session.pop('username', None)
       return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Вопрос в следующем. Вот для одного пользователя все понятно, а когда их достаточно большое количество, откуда мне брать этот `'username'`, чтобы завершить сессию именно для пользователя, нажавшего `logout` на сайте?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Каждый пользователь имеет свою собственную сессию, в которой хранятся данные, относящиеся только лишь к нему.

Если достаточно сильно упростить, то сессии можно представить себе в виде словаря, где ключом будет некий идентификатор пользователя, который присылает нам браузер, а значением - данные сессии:

```
{
    'aa04c3e7-c9f8-4d6f-b859-0162cf5b5af4': {
        'id': 20,
        'last_login': 1478351885
        'username': 'Aleksey'
    },
    '5253b4fe-cf1d-4b76-8d73-e125457d8cf7': {
        'id': 21,
        'last_login': 1478323910
        'username': 'Ivan'
    },
    'f1e7f9a8-858c-4613-994d-340022420d62': {
        'id': 22,
        'last_login': 1478351918
    }
}
```

1. Пользователь переходит по ссылке `/logout`.
2. Flask получает от браузера идентификатор сессии пользователя и передаёт его менеджеру сессий. Например такой: `5253b4fe-cf1d-4b76-8d73-e125457d8cf7`.
3. Менеджер сессий, на основании полученного идентификатора определяет вошедшего как пользователя с `id = 21` и подставляет данные его сессии в объект `session`, который будет доступен в функции/виде `logout()`:

`session = {
        'id': 21,
        'last_login': 1478323910,
        'username': 'Ivan'
    }`

Comment: Это я более или менее понимаю, не понимаю, что требуется непосредственно в коде.

Comment: @dyop, `'username'` ниоткуда брать не нужно, это текстовый ключ объекта `session`:
`session => {'username': 'Ivan'}`;
`session.pop('username', None)`;
`session => {}`;
В вашем коде уже всё сделано вполне логично, команда `.pop` удаляет из сессии имя пользователя, если оно там есть.

Comment: А разве сессия не заменится? Пришел первый скажем `'Ivan'`, прошел через `login`, приходит другой `'Alex'`, и если делать `print(session)`, значение меняется.

Comment: @dyop, нет, значение не заменяется. Для каждого пользователя значения свои, они просто подменяются в зависимости от пользователя, но никуда не деваются.